# Saving a custom class into array inside user defaults

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

Let's say I have a class called `Lop`. Then I would like to save instances of it to user defaults in some array, and also retrieve objects from this array.

I have created the `NSCoding` method in that class and now trying to write functions to save/retrieve and having hard time.

To add for example:

```
   func addLop(newlop:ALop)
    {
        
        //get defaults array(already archived)
        let lops  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lops")
        
        //add a new lop class, archived, to the user defaults array
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newlop)
        lops?.addObject(data)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lops, forKey: "lops")
        
        
    }
```

Which I don't really know if works because the retrieve function I just couldn't handle to write:

```
    func getLops()->Array<Any>
    {
        //get defaults array(archived)
        let lops  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lops")
      
        // here I should loop over this array of archived classes,
        // then turn all of them into original unarchived classes
        // and return
    }
```

1. How can I write a function that returns the array of unarchived classes ?
2. When saving (if done right) how can I check if a class already exist in user defaults before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(lops[i] as! NSData)`
2. First you can archive checked object to `NSData` and then check equality (by calling `data.isEqual(lops[i])`) of that `NSData` to each archived `NSData` you have already stored in `NSUserDetaults`.

Other way around is by unarchiving each already stored object from `NSUserDefaults` and checking equality of `ALop` objects. You will have to implement `bool isEqual(other : NSObject)` method in your `ALop` class and compare in it all properties of two objects, e.g.

```
bool isEqual(other : NSObject)
{
    let otherALop = other as? Alop
    if otherALop == nil {return false }
    if otherALop == self { return true }

    bool result = true
    result = result && (self.property == otherALop!.property)
    // ... for all properties repeat previous line 
    return result 
}
```

Be aware that `NSUserDefaults` are limited to store not more than ~64 KB, and are not intended to store your model layer data objects, only app's preferences.

Comment: So where you suggest to store my model layer objects ? NSFile ?

Comment: CoreData is the common, native, and straightforward ORM framework to save model layer objects into the database.